# iOS / Swift: Get the screen path

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad

I would like to draw a border around the screen. But for that, I need:

- the radius of the 4 corners
- the coordinates of the notch (if there is one)

Do you know how we can get this kind of information?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the border to be drawn outside the notch or within the notch?

Comment: Outside the notch, to draw a border around the screen

Answer (score 7):

Use this extension to retrieve corner radius:

```
extension UIScreen {
public var displayCornerRadius: CGFloat {
    guard let cornerRadius = self.value(forKey:"_displayCornerRadius") as? CGFloat else {
        return 0
    }
    return cornerRadius
 }
}
```

In View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
      view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
      view.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
      view.layer.cornerRadius = UIScreen.main.displayCornerRadius
  }

}
```

Comment: This is a private API, will this pass Apple Review?